# How can I use 3 chart types in excel over both axis OR otherwise properly show the data for multiple data sources?

Tags: excel, bar-chart, excel-2013

Sorry about the title, it was hard to figure out how to word this. So, my main problem is a Total Count column represent the overall quantity, but the other columns are PART of a Total Count column. This wouldn't be so bad except the other columns may be part of each other too. Meaning, for like 11/26/18... the Total Count column is ALL of the Item Count, but some of the other ones may be in New PR Count too, but not necessarily all. Same thing with Dropped Outside LT and Dropped Late columns. They are all part of the Total Count column but all are not necessarily separate.

I feel nothing short of a bunch of complex formulae or macros will fix this so, what is my best option to show at least the individual counts? I was thinking to have the Total Count column as a Clustered Column chart type, the other columns as a Stacked Column and the 2 lines as is. Or all columns just be Clustered Columns and lines as is. What do you all think would best show this data?

So sadly, due to proprietary, I am told at work not to upload an image of the chart. FUN. So, here is what I have..
7 Series - 5 Series are Stacked Columns in Primary Axis, 2 Series are Line with Markers in Secondary Axis. Each column is for a single week's entry of data (so based around a Date entry.

The two Line with Markers are percentages (Secondary Vertical (Value) Axis) on right side of chart. On left side is Total Count (Verical (Value) Axis) basically showing a Count being connected to the Total Count column.

Comment: You can make two separate charts then make one transparent and lay it on top of the other...

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah, I read that when I was trying to search online. Is this pretty much the only way to handle this without like an addon or some complex macro, would you think?

Comment: Had "one" chart that was actually 6... worked very well... looked simple... :)